# How to change Proton variables in Heroic?

Tags: wine, gog, steam-deck, heroic-games-launcher

I have recently got a Steam Deck. I have tried installing the Heroic games launcher on it. A game I have tried to install on it from GoG crashes shortly after opening. I looked it up on ProtonDB and people are suggesting various parameters to fix it, such as `PROTON_NO_ESYNC=1 PROTON_NO_FSYNC=1 %command%`. I am not, however, aware of where/how I should apply these parameters.

How do you set these "Launch options"?

Comment: These look like environment variables. In most Linux systems you can use `export EXAMPLE=yes && %command%` which will set the env var, and run the command.

Comment: @Neon1024 In what context do I run them and what do you mean by "and run the command"? Do you mean the command to launch the game through proton? How would I obtain the command that does that? I have been using a graphical launcher.

Comment: Ahok, yes these would be for a command line interface, apologies, didn't realise it was a GUI

Answer (score 1):

You would add these launch options within the game's "Properties" menu under the "General" tab, though it looks a little different depending on if you are attempting to do so in either Game Mode or Desktop Mode

**In Game Mode**: From your library, select the game you wish to adjust, then choose the gear icon on the right-hand side of the screen, and then choosing "Properties...". The properties menu should open which will be on the "General" tab by default, and from there you can scroll down to the bottom and get to the box to enter launch options

**In Desktop Mode**: Simply right click on the game's entry in your library list and choose "Properties...", and from there the launch options box should be visible to you

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is useful, however my question was about setting launch options within the Heroic Games Launcher rather than the built in steam launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

First, you can add the game to your Steam library and use the launch options there.  This can be done with games outside of Steam.

Second, you can add a line like `export MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=150` to the start.sh file where Heroic installed the game.